# cannot add foreign key constraint Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I first created all the tables without their foreign keys, I then added the foreign keys for each table, starting with the first table, i got this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL
  : alter table `accounts` add constraint accounts_client_id_foreign foreign
  key (`client_id`) references `clients` (`id`))
```

Here's my code:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('accounts', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

        $table->bigInteger('id');

        $table->integer('client_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients');

        $table->integer('emp_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('emp_id')->references('id')->on('employees');

        $table->string('type');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I tried without $table->engine='innoDB'; but same error

Plus, i tried to separate the foreign keys:

```
Schema::table('accounts', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients');
        $table->foreign('emp_id')->references('id')->on('employees');
    });
```

I got this error:

```
Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'accounts' already exists
```

So when I deleted and re-migrate i get the first error

So whats happening?

Comment: Do you have data in the tables that doesn't conform to the fk constraint? You could try adding nullable to the foreign keys

Comment: I still didn't add data to the tables

Answer (score 0):

I've got same error, it feels like bug to me. What I did is created different migrations for foreign keys. So, first you create table with fields, then (in next by date migration) you add foreign keys.

Then I rolled back all migrations and reruned them with `php artisan migrate`. It worked for me, I hope it'll also work for you.

Comment: So you're saying I should add date to the table before adding the foreign keys?

Comment: No, just be sure migration with foreign keys have latest date in it's filename.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please upvote and choose it as best answer.

Answer (score 0):

I foresee you created the related table("clients") specifying the primary key/id as this

```
$table->bigInteger('id');
```

or

```
$table->integer('id');
```

which will cause problem in the sense that your foreign key constraint 
is being specified as

$table->integer('client_id')->unsigned();

whiles the primary key/id does not have the **unsigned()** constraint assigned to it.

So change the primary key of the related table to

```
$table->bigInteger('id')->unsigned();
```

or

```
$table->integer('id')->unsigned();
```

And if you are using **bigInteger** for the primary key try and make the foerign key also **bigInteger**. Don't forget to use **unsigned()** for both (the primary key and the foreign key).